# Bulk setting hashes in Redis

Tags: memory, optimization, hash, redis

I'm trying to store in Redis some entities which have an id and some properties:

```
id string(30)
firstname string(20)
lastname string(20)
bio string(150)
```

I've read in the docs that the best way to store this in Redis would be hashes. is this correct? 
I am receiving this entities in batches of 1000 and i would need to bulk store them in Redis, since doing it one by one, i assume would be very slow. Is this possible?
Any better idea on how to store and import this?

Comment: http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert Has some information on this subject & a [kind of related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7505508/586621).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption about doing it one by one will be slow is wrong. It will not be slow. Redis is very fast. You can get the idea from below benchmark:-

```
./redis-benchmark -r 1000000 -n 2000000 -t get,set,lpush,lpop -P 16 -q
SET: 552028.75 requests per second
GET: 707463.75 requests per second
LPUSH: 767459.75 requests per second
LPOP: 770119.38 requests per second
```

More benchmark statistics:-

http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks

As you mentioned entities are in the batch of 1000 which should not take more than few milliseconds. Just make sure you are using  PIPELINE.