# Bulk writing in Redis

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I have to Insert millions of row of mysql Database into redis in python. I am currently using pipline for the same but It is talking too much time and memory. Can you suggest the better way to implement this.

Comment: Could you paste some of your code? How are you getting your rows from the mysql database?

Comment: using Select * from table_name and to load in redis I am using this code          

import redis
def load(pdtDict):
    redIs = redis.Redis()
    pipe = redIs.pipeline()
    for key in pdtDict.keys():
        pipe.hmset(self.seller+":"+str(key),pdtDict[key])
    pipe.execute()

Comment: Some links that might help you; See here: (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/redis-db/pipeline/redis-db/D4V6kDJNDsI/1-vqnsCxJ18J) and here: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7505508/2759336)

Comment: Can you explain  how to insert in batch ?

Comment: Edit your question with sample source data, you may get better help with that.